# cumulative distribution function plotting

Tags: r, perl

I have some values from different repetitions of different experiments and I need to plot cumulative distribution function. You can see a fraction of my file below. can you help me how can i do that.

```
Experiment Replication Obs
General0 0 1.294602161803 
General0 0 1.094633445207 
General0 0 0.844958280328 
General0 0 0.599093485481 
General0 0 0.362884584822 
General0 0 0.132874339382 
General0 0 0.006860913445 
General0 0 0.010738332566
```

Comment: The `R` function `ecdf` ([link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ecdf.html)) might help you here.

Comment: yes, of course but do you know how can i get it for each experiment and shows the mean of different repetitions' cdf?

Comment: Something like that: 
`ex1 <- ecdf(data$Obs[data$Experiment == "General0"]` and so on for each experiment (if there are many experiments, you could make a loop). To plot:
`plot(ex1)`
`lines(ex2)` and so on. To add the means as vertical lines: `abline(v=mean(data$Obs[data$Experiment == "General0"])` for each experiment, maybe with different colours.

Comment: can you explain more.